# What is the difference between ADDCOLUMNS and CALCULATETABLE?

Tags: powerbi

I am looking for example to understand the difference between ADDCOLUMNS and CALCULATETABLE. Any DAX example showing how these can be used will be helpful.

Comment: CALCULATETABLE filters a table. ADDCOLUMNS adds a column to a table. They don't have anything in common.

Answer (score 1):

ADDCOLUMNS adds new columns to an existing table with calculated expressions, while CALCULATETABLE creates a new table based on a filter expression of an existing table.

```
ADDCOLUMNS(Sales, "Total Sales", SUM(Sales[Amount]))
```

would add a new column called "Total Sales" to the "Sales" table and calculate the total sales amount in that column.

```
CALCULATETABLE(FILTER(Sales, Sales[Region] = "East"), "East Sales")
```

would create a new table called "East Sales" that contains only the rows from the "Sales" table where the "Region" column is equal to "East"

Comment: This is not entirely correct - both would create new tables, either temporary tables used in calculations or tables persisted to the data model.

Comment: Can you create the answer or edit it